# get JSON response status message in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc

This is my code of jquery...
when i hit the api it return the response in json format

**i am getting this response on console**

```
Object {status_code: "fail", status_message: "Something get wrong we will reach u soon."}
```

I want to get the status code = fail in response and do something in jquery like show the alert so i wrote this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#resend").click(function() {
var mobileNumber = $("#mobileNumber").val();
    var emailId = $("#emailId").val();
     var dataresendotp = 'email='+ emailId + '&mobile=' + mobileNumber;    
     console.log(dataresendotp); 
   if(mobileNumber=='' )
    {
alert("nothing in it");
    }
    else
    {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
         url : '/geniedoc/api/user/otp?',
         data: dataresendotp,
   success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        if ( response === false )
        {
            alert("something went wrong");

        }
  }
});}
    return false;
    });

});
```

but it's not working can someone suggest how to get the response from json in jquery?

Comment: what is the actual response in XHR

Comment: Object {status_code: "fail", status_message: "Something get wrong we will reach u soon."}

Comment: you can access it using `response.status_code`

Comment: yes i just made a change and it works

Comment: @user6409738 thats great!